# Modify salesforce list view to add in custom link

Tags: visualforce, list-view

Is it possible to add a custom link to my salesforce list views?

My use case is as follows: I have a bunch of users, and depending on where the user is in our internal process, we want to be able to click on a button which will automatically take us to a custom screen to fill out the information to move the user to the next step in the process.

E.g

```
User | User Progress

ID1  | First stage

ID2  | Second Stage

ID3  | First stage
```

where clicking on first stage will take us to a custom page to fill in the data required to move the user to the next stage.

---

Currently our solution is for the admin to click on the user (ID1 or so), that takes them to that users' page where we embed a button to kick off the process but if possible we'd like to remove this "unnecessary" middle step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For List View Buttons you need to implement the `StandardSetController` in your controller extension ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm)), but this will not solve your problem, because it is on top of the list. So far there is no custom Button or Link that you can display IN the list, related to a certain record.

[This answers approach](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DiVOQA0) is to create a url-formula field on the object itself.

Comment: "Because it is on top of the list"? Sorry I don't really understand.

Comment: @user49458 where the "new" button on related lists is located at.

Comment: Awesome thank you I THINK I might be able to do what I want but you've definitely given me a starting point.